# How does distinctUntilKeyChanged() works?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular component I have a list of cart items that can be modified using inputs (each item has it's own input) that has `(change)=onChange($event, cartItem)` on it. `onChange()` is pushing cartItem with modified amount to a `Subject`. Every item is of type:

```
export class CartItemOutput {
  user_id: number;
  item_id: number;
  amount: number;
  price: number;
  item_name: string;
  photo: string;
}
```

I want to only make API calls if there is a cart item that was last modified some time ago (now it's 500ms) and modification did not resulted in the same amount. In my `ngOnInit()` I have:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subject
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilKeyChanged("amount")
        )
      .subscribe((data: CartItemOutput) => {
        //log modified item
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

If I delete `distinctUntilKeyChanged("amount")` everything works as I expected and cart item is logged into console only if it wasn't modified in the last 500ms. But I don't want to log if item's amount was modified e.g. from 2 to 1 and back to 2. The problem is, with `distinctUntilKeyChanged("amount")` the item is logged only once.

EDIT

Upon further inspection I found out that when I changed:

```
.pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
        distinctUntilKeyChanged('amount')
        )
```

into

```
.pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
        distinctUntilChanged((p,q) => {
          console.log(p);
          console.log(q);
          return p.amount == q.amount
        })
        )
```

Two values p and q are exactly the same when editing the same item (When I edit item with id e.g. 2 and change it's amount to let's say 7, both p and q have amount of 7). Then when I edit different item, p and q are different and `data` is logged into console.

Comment: Could you clearify what the input and your expected output is? What is logged only once? `distinctUntilKeyChanged` compares the current to the previous item.

Comment: I have an input that modifies amount on some cart item based on cartItem provided in `onChange()`. I am pushing that CartItemOutput with modified amount to Subject. I would like to log only if amount on item has changed to something different. Let's say some item has amount of 2. I would like to log that modified item to console only if user has changed the amount to something different than 2.

Comment: Yes, that's what `distinctUntilKeyChanged` does. What isn't working for you? Given an example.

Comment: I know that it should work like I described. The biggest problem is I don't really know why it doesn't work. For example: I start with an item with amount = 2. I then modify it using my input field and change amount to 7. Modified item is logged into console, so everything seems to be in order. Now, I modify amount and change it t oseomething else than 7 or 2. As I understand it, the modified item should be logged into console. But it isn't. And from now on no matter how I modify the amount nothing is logged into console.

Comment: are you modifying the item in place and pushing the same instance? if so, the amount field will always be equal between one item and the "next".

Comment: You should look into working with immutable data. Assign and push in one go with: `subject.next(item =  { ...item, amount: x })`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Clashsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4138801/clashsoft)'s and [fridoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9423231/fridoo) comments I managed to get it working. I was pushing new values to subject incorrectly.
My code was looking like this:

```
  onChange(event: any, cartItem: CartItemOutput) {
    
    cartItem.amount = parseInt(event.target.value);
    this.subject.next(cartItem);
  }
```

where cartItem was the item edited by input. Passing it to `next()` function was then causing previous and next items to be the same, just like Clashsoft said.

Now my code looks like this:

```
  onChange(event: any, cartItem: CartItemOutput) {
    cartItem.amount = parseInt(event.target.value);
    this.subject.next({...cartItem, amount: parseInt(event.target.value)});
  }
```

and everything is working fine with `distinctUntilKeyChanged('amount')`.